# Degradation of carbon anode in electrolysis of copper sulfate

Tags: electrochemistry, electrolysis

I'm electrolysing a copper sulfate solution with a 12 volt DC supply using two carbon electrodes. The anode is reducing in mass and becoming thinner. Is there any way I can overcome this problem?

Comment: Is the electrode rather mechanically desintegrated , e.g. by the internal oxygen creation ? Or, is the material rather disappearing ? I remember home experiments from my childhood, and the carbon electrode from a battery cell created a carbon dust.

Comment: The carbon electrode has mechanically disintegrated into a dust at the bottom. I would like to know whether I can use a steel anode instead because I do not have access to a platinum electrode. My question is “will a steel rod not disintegrate or corrode?” Thanks.

Comment: I suppose stainless steel will survive. Try rather the steel plate, to keep low current density.